# Вытащить определенные слова из строк которые начинаются одинаково

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть текст:

```
abc cab abc 
123: abc cab abc cab
abc cab abc
123: abc cab abc cab
```

Нужно вытащить все abc и cab из строк которые начинаются с 123:
Если `(\babc\b)|(\bcab\b)` то тащит со всех строк. Если что-то типа такого `(^123.*(?|(\babc\b)|(\bcab\b)).*)` то вытаскивает из нужных строк только последнее совпадение. Пробовал такое `^123:(?=.*\b(cab|bac)\b)` но тоже только последнее

Comment: а просто проверить начало строки вы сначала не можете, не прибегая к регулярным выражениям, раз уж это константа у вас?

Comment: Вытаскивайте не 1 группу, а 0

Comment: 123:( ?[a-c]{3})+; либо жёстко 123:( [a-c]{3}){4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^123:).*?\b\K(?:cab|bac)\b
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/svM5sm/1).

*Подробности*

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^123:)` - `123:` в начале строки или конец предыдущего совпадения
- `.*?` - ноль и более символов, отличных от символов переноса строки, как можно меньше
- `\b` - граница слова
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий текст из буфера текущего совпадения
- `(?:cab|bac)` - слова `или`
- `\b` - граница слова.